# Facing issue in DateFormat parsing

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat, date-formatting

With the below code snippet I am getting exception in Java SE 1.7 environment.Can anybody help me figure out problem with this code.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date date = df.parse("10:00 PM");
```

Exception Details :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10:00 PM"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
at com.premute.ModuleTest.main(ModuleTest.java:74)
```

Comment: Tried it with 2 `a`'s in the format string?

Comment: I already tried but with 2 a's its not working.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to have a default `Locale` which cannot parse the English `PM`. Use the [overloaded `SimpleDateFormat` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-) which accepts a `Locale` and provide it with an appropriate instance.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```